# C Sockets: Redirecting buffer to another file

Tags: c, linux, sockets, buffer

If this has been asked before in a different wording, I apologize.

Heres my issue. I have a Linux TCP server client relationship and in a certain part of my code, the server will write() chunks (lets say 512 bytes) of a file buffer to the client. I am wanting the client to reconstruct the file on the other side by somehow redirecting the buffer chunks outward to a already made file (mimicking a copy effect). I was considering a middle man whom would translate the buffer into characters and then use fprintf etc. to push the information to a file (this is the only way I can conceive how). However, this idea does not work when working with binary files as ascii would mess up the binary.

Is there a way to redirect a file buffer pointer into another file?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read a buffer from the socket using `recv`, and write it to the file using `fwrite`. When you open the local file, before sure to use `"wb"` as the mode.

Edit: Here's a sketch of the general idea:

```
socket input = open_socket(server, server_port);   
FILE *file = fopen("localfile.bin", "wb");
char buffer[some_size];

do { 
    size_t received = recv(input, some_size);
    fwrite(buffer, received, 1, file);
} while (received != 0);
```

Comment: let me try this out. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Actually I may have used the wrong word while explaining my problem (its late where I am :P). I opened a file in the server, and am streaming the contents by writing the FILE * fp to the client in chunks. The client should get the chunks and direct them into a local file with the same name. If your solution still works, let me know. (BTW .bin or .txt are okay given right precautions ahead of time).

Comment: @Chris Allen: yes -- shouldn't be a problem, as long as the server sends the data out un-modified.

Comment: I'm newish to the site so I'm not sure where to put follow up question. I have a file pointer on the client side (say fp = NULL) and I have the recv statement set up as recv(socket, &fp, bytes, 0) where bytes is the size of my test file lol.txt (30bytes). I have my fwrite statement set up like fwrite(fp, bytes, 1, outfile) where outfile is a FILE pointer to the destination file created with wb. I'm getting seg faults on the fwrite section. Is it possible that you can point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @Chris Allen: if `fp=NULL`, then you *don't* have a valid point to a FILE -- you need to open a file with `fopen` (and get a non-NULL) pointer before you can use `fwrite` successfully.

Comment: Wow, thanks again for the quick reply (very grateful). Just to confirm I'm on the same level, fp starts out NULL (gcc warns about the variable being uninitialized else wise) but then gets it values from recv by taking in the chunks and then dumping its content into the outfile. So fp is just a middle man that redirects the stream to the outfile (the newly create client lol.txt in which outfile is pointing to). fp is not associated with a file as it is just a cog that redirects data. That is why it is set to NULL.

Comment: could I be able to just cut out fp and directly send the data to the outfile?

Comment: @Chris Allen: I've edited a rough sketch into the answer above.

Comment: ah... Yeah I was out of sync with what you were saying.